# Would dirt hide a scent from Rhino-Snakes?

Tags: escape, senses

Deep in the forests live great predators that I shall refer to as Rhino-Snakes:
These are creatures with the features of both serpents and rhinocerotes. In particular, they have a large equine-type nose much like that of a rhino. Their tongue, however, is forked like that of a snake, and their vomeronasal organ is rather large. Unfortunately for them their tongue is too thick to be flicked around, and can only be stuck out of the lips as in fork-tongued lizards. Their senses of smell are therefore quite powerful, and they are willing to follow any human that crosses them wherever they go

Given their strong and distinctive olfaction and the dire stakes for detection, would standard methods like washing and applying things like mud and leaves be sufficient to get away?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

Wild animals are constantly exposed to all kinds of dirt and debris but that doesn’t prevent smell from being an effective way to track prey or detect predators. Any animal that relies on scent to track prey will be able to get past the paltry application of mud. Consider bloodhounds for a moment. Bloodhounds can track humans for miles across all kinds of terrain, and rolling around in mud would do you no favors in trying to escape one.